# ApiProperty not reflecting the type of data i want

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I'm creating a POST endpoint that will receive an object with one property: returnIds. This return ids will be an array of NUMBERS

```
{
  "returnIds": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

For this i create this DTO

```
 @ApiProperty()  
 returnIds: number[]
```

The problem is that swagger is showing me this

[image]

what i need to change that the shown example is instead "string" a 0 or something related with a number?

This is my endpoint

[image]

Thank u a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@ApiProperty({ type: [Number] })` to designate it's supposed to be an array of numbers. [Just like it's mentioned in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters#arrays)

Comment: Thank u for the answer Jay. But i need to the answer be { returnIds:[NUMBERS] }

Comment: Nevermind, i read wrong. That was the answer. Thank u a lot and sorry for the dumb question. I forgot something very basic